# Unable to authorize the org in vscode

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, salesforcedx-cli-auth

When i tried to authorize the org via vscode this issue is showing.After killing process id 1717,another issue is showing.Here is the issue

> { Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>     errno: 'ENOENT',
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'spawn cmd',
>     path: 'cmd',
>     spawnargs:
>      [ '/c',
>        'start',
>        '""',
>        '/b',
>        'https://login.salesforce.com//services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=15a762a515e8^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=RrzMT4T6wxF_GxYsL3d1WACQHHLM_mNFVBn9Q6zkLrk' ] }
>   { Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>     errno: 'ENOENT',
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'spawn cmd',
>     path: 'cmd',
>     spawnargs:
>      [ '/c',
>        'start',
>        '""',
>        '/b',
>        'https://login.salesforce.com//services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=15a762a515e8^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=RrzMT4T6wxF_GxYsL3d1WACQHHLM_mNFVBn9Q6zkLrk' ] }
>   { Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>     errno: 'ENOENT',
>     code: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'spawn cmd',
>     path: 'cmd',
>     spawnargs:
>      [ '/c',
>        'start',
>        '""',
>        '/b',
>        'https://login.salesforce.com//services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=15a762a515e8^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=RrzMT4T6wxF_GxYsL3d1WACQHHLM_mNFVBn9Q6zkLrk' ] }

How to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

I checked system variables found the cause of the problem: missing `C:\Windows\System32\` variable.

I added it and that solved my problem

Hope, it help you too.

Comment: I dont know why it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the environment variables for your system? 
You must add below the environment variables.

JAVA, Salesforce CLI, VS Code, System32

Answer (score 0):

If your are connecting to a sandbox, edit your **sfdx-project.json** file to set *sfdcLoginUrl* to https://test.salesforce.com before you authorize the org.

Here's the code that I'm using

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com/",
  "sourceApiVersion": "49.0"
}
```

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm